# Wordpress Blog Redirect Solution

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress blog, and I am having problems figuring the right solution to my problem.

I have specific posts that i wanted redirected to an external alternative pages, then I want a catch for any other links visited on the site to redirect to a certain other page.

What do you think is the best solution to this? htaccess? a plugin? and how do I implement?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem **and what has been done so far to solve it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) The Yoast SEO premium plugin has a very nice redirect manager. If you're willing to pay for it, this is your best bet. Purchase, download, and install the plugin. Then, configure it in the dashboard: https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/redirects-manager/

2) You can do this all manually using .htaccess. There are several good example tutorials of how to do this, such as [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules), [here](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners), or [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708).